# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module 'mysite.routing'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-import, importerror

I am trying to create a webapp using django and while running it on my local system, I am getting stucked here because of this issue.Even though the asgi,wsgi and settings are configured properly.Its showing that it cant import asgi application.Can someone check what's the issue is ?

```
asgi.py

"""
ASGI config for mysite project.
It exposes the ASGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.
For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/asgi/
"""

import os
import sys
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
# django.setup()
application = get_asgi_application()
```

```
wsgi.py
"""
WSGI config for mysite project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

At first I thought it was about the Base dir not getting initialised, show I tried using pathlib, but still it didnt work

```
setting.py

"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
# BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'i1+q47!dh6p&-8*$+k%nf2bwbzl6!b^a%k=0a-k&4hsxv)ccup'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = "mysite.routing.application"
```

```
Starting ASGI/Channels version 2.1.7 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Exception ignored in thread started by: <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f3f6afc4f70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/markins/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/markins/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py", line 101, in inner_run
    application=self.get_application(options),
  File "/home/markins/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py", line 126, in get_application
    return StaticFilesWrapper(get_default_application())
  File "/home/markins/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 35, in get_default_application
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module %r" % path)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module 'mysite.routing'
```

Comment: Should the `ASGI_APPLICATION` setting be `"mysite.asgi.application"`, since the file is named `asgi.py`?

Comment: Yeah I tried it , it didnt got resolved

Comment: Did you get a different exception?

Comment: No I got the same exception only

Comment: @ManojTolagekar I tried using it showed that it could not import routing

Comment: @Markins what versions of django and channels do you have installed?

Comment: channels - 2.1.7 and django - 2.1.8 @IainShelvington

Comment: @Markins looks like you copied that asgi.py from docs for a newer version of django/channels, see the 2.x channels docs for the correct `routing.py/asgi.py` code https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/2.x/installation.html. Django didn't support ASGI before version 3 so `from django.core.asgi import ...` is most likely an import error

Comment: @IainShelvington thanks your idea actually worked its was an import error actually due to older versions